# Order custom taxonomy by date

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have custom taxonomy called series.
I want to have a page where it lists all the Series with latest on the top.

Series

- Series about fish

  - Post 1
  - Post 2
- Series about dog

  - Post 1
  - Post 2

I created a taxonomy-series.php which list the individual series, but I go to http://example.com/series. I get a 404.

Do I need to create a separate page on the theme? to list al the series arranged by date?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has no an archvie for a taxonomy, but only archive for terms.

E.g., you can have the url `example.com/series/series-about-fish` thta displays all the post in that series, but there is **no** an archive `example.com/series/` that display the posts in all the series.

Easiest way to achieve this is create a [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates), create a page in dashboard with slug `series` and assign the template, then in the template file create a that displays posts using a custom `WP_Query` with the proper taxonomy_query argument..

If every post belong only to **one** serie, it's easy write **a custom function that return a multidimensional array of posts, where every first level item is an array with 2 elements: one keysed *'term'* contain the *series* term object, the second keyed *'posts'* contain all the posts for that series**:

In `functions.php` put something like:

```
function get_series_posts() { 
  $terms = get_terms('series', array('fields'=>'ids') );
  $tax_query = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'series',
    'field' => 'id',
    'terms' => $terms,
  );
  $args = array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'tax_query' => array($tax_query));
  $q = new WP_Query( $args );
  $posts_ordered = array();
  $done = 0;
  while ( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post();
    global $post;
    // all the post series array
    $series = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'series');
    // the last series (if there is only one series per post no matter the order)
    $serie = array_shift( $series );
    if ( ! isset($posts_ordered[$serie->slug]) )
      $posts_ordered[$serie->slug] = array('term' => $serie);
    if ( ! isset($posts_ordered[$serie->slug]['posts']) )
      $posts_ordered[$serie->slug]['posts'] = array();
    $posts_ordered[$serie->slug]['posts'][] = $post;
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  return $posts_ordered;
}
```

After that, in your page template you can do:

```
$posts = get_series_posts();

if ( ! empty($posts) ) {
  echo '<ul>'; // open series list
  foreach ( $posts as $loop_data) {
    echo '<li>'; // open series list item
    echo '<a href="' . get_term_link($loop_data['term'], 'series') . '">';
    echo $loop_data['term']->name . '</a>';
    echo '<ul>'; // open post list
    global $post;
    foreach ( $loop_data['posts'] as $post) { // loop throug posts of a series
      setup_postdata($post);
      printf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', get_permalink(), get_the_title() );
    }
    echo '</ul>'; // close post list;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    echo '</li>'; // close series list item
  }
  echo '</ul>'; // close series list
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it is giving me a blank page, I am wondering is anything missing in the function

Comment: Thanks mate.Seems to be working. But only showing one series.

Comment: This is my taxonomy code
http://pastebin.com/2UCj97Vm

Comment: I have all these series.  
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2160506/Screen%20shot%202013-09-25%20at%2010.42.39%20AM.png
I have actually tired this plugin as well, same thing arrange alphabetically rather than the latest on.
http://wordpress.org/plugins/organize-series/

Comment: @user1535162 I was asking if same post belong to more than one series. E.g. If the post 'Example' has attached 2 series: 'alternative-for-alternatives' *and* 'buy-side-search-for-liquidity'. In this case the code fail, otherwise should work, it worked for me. I tested creating 3 series (registered using your code), and creating 6 posts, 2 per series. My code display correctly a list of 3 series with a sublist of 2 posts for each series...

Comment: Oh okay, nope all the series has different post